# I Eats My Spinach

Tags: third-person-singular

"I Eats My Spinach" is an old Popeye the sailor episode (1933). Shouldn't it be "I Eat My Spinach" instead? How come there's the 3rd person singular "s" there?

Reference: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0024152/

And here the episode itself: https://vimeo.com/152216667

Comment: It's a deliberately "affected pseudo-dialectal" usage, similar to comedian Ali G's [Is it because I **is** black?!?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHJmY6h-LV0) I'd advise you ***not*** to copy this kind of grammatical rule-breaking as a non-native speaker unless you're certain none of your audience will think you don't actually *know* the "correct" version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a pattern in some dialects of English called the [Northern subject rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_subject_rule) where the terminal **-s** is frequently added to present-tense verbs, particularly when describing habitual actions.  This pattern particularly common in [Newfoundland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_English), but it's a non-standard practice and should be avoided by people who do not naturally speak these particular dialects.

Popeye's dialect isn't a precise match for anything in the real world, but it's similar what you'd hear from a working-class, early 20th-century resident of New England.  I suspect that the writers who created Popeye were at least unconsciously aware of this Northern subject rule as being used by non-formally-educated sailors from the northern Atlantic coast of North America.

---

Edited: I'm linking [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqLuIXwsLDw) I found of a couple of Newfoundland natives deliberately exaggerating their local accent.  At about 1:05, you hear one of them saying:

> "I likes the gravy; I sweats gravy in the mornings."

Then, at 4:25, he lists a bunch of other common uses, including **I wants..., I needs..., I likes...,** and **I loves you**.  I'm pretty sure that both Popeye and Olive Oyl (his girlfriend) say "I loves you" to each other in the cartoons.

I know someone from Newfoundland who has mostly adapted to "standard" Canadian English grammar (though he still has quite a strong accent), but occasionally I hear him say something like, "I knows that."

Comment: That's very interesting, you could include that Newfoundland video in your answer as an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is part of Popeye's own unique pattern of speech (possibly based on a New England dialect, see Canadian Yankee's answer), along with such phrases as:

> I yam what I yam and that's all what I yam (I'm Popeye the sailor man!)
>
> That's all I can stands, 'cause I can't stands n'more!
>
> Well blow me down!

plus his [characteristic laugh.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRcyvBOWd2o)

Many famous cartoon and other characters have similar uniquely identifiable patterns of speech and catch-phrases, such as Bugs Bunny's

> [Nyaah .... What's up Doc?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwLn_His9Yw)

Or Elmer Fudd's pronunciation of "r" as "w":

> [Be vewwy vewwy quiet, I'm hunting wabbits.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jniBcWRT91U)

Plus many, many more.  These should only be imitated if you intend to sound like these characters.

Comment: It's not unique to Popeye.  See my answer referencing the [Northern subject rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_subject_rule).  You're correct that a non-native speaker shouldn't be imitating this usage.

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Thanks, I did not know that.  Edited my answer.  Are there any videos of people speaking this dialect?  I know the New England dialect has elongated short "a" sounds (e.g. [Pepperidge Faaahm remembers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXUxLqqmhNs)), and other differences, but otherwise I can't recall hearing anyone speak with the Northern Subject rule.  Might just be a faulty memory.

Comment: I found [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqLuIXwsLDw) of a couple of people deliberately playing up their Newfoundland accents.  At about 1:05, you can hear one of them say, "I likes the gravy; I sweats gravy in the mornings."

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Perfect!  I can only understand about half of what they're saying!  :)