# Why the verbs in this series are not conjugated properly?

Tags: grammar

For this old Popeye series, He always use the conjugation that is for the pronons (He and She). Eg: I remembers instead of I remember. Why does Popeye speak like that? Is it just a funny thing to make people laugh? Or Is it something with the grammar? Or Is it something related to how people spoke more than 50 years ago?

https://www.popcornflix.com/watch/channel/family-and-kids-tv/series/18-3yt3u7zwtbni-popeye-and-son/episode/18-q906cb54b3ef-popeye-and-son-111-orchid-you-not-aint-mythbehavin

Comment: He's talking a dialect rather than standard English, intended to show that he is uneducated. There are dialects which use verbs in that way, but I don't know whether Popeye's dialect is a real one, or one put together for the purposes of the show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I Eats My Spinach](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154523/i-eats-my-spinach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I remembers" is not specifically "for pronouns", it is simply th third-person form:

> - He remembers the event.
> - John remembers the event.

The character of Popeye the Sailor often mis-used third-person forms in the first person. This served as a speech tag to identify the character. I strongly suspect it was originally done to fit the stereotype of the common sailor as uneducated and crude of speech. I don't know of any authentic accounts of sailors using third-person forms in the first person, however. I suppose this was just invented by th writers.  I believe it was also considered funny at the time.

### Edit

<s>I wonder if this may not have been intended to suggest [Appalachian English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English), but if so it is a very poor representation of that dialect.</s> Apparently this is not accurate, Andrew's comment cites [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154523/i-eats-my-spinach) to say that it is based on a Newfoundland dialect.

Comment: This question has been asked before.  It's actually a Newfoundland dialect, the primary port of call for American sailing in the 19th century.  See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154523/i-eats-my-spinach for more details.